# Getting probability of class using naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability, text-classification, naivebayes

I am trying to classify input with two classes, here is the code. `dino` and `crypto` are two classes:

```
for w, cnt in list(counts.items()): #count is dict with word and it's count value
    p_word = vocab[w] / sum(vocab.values()) 
    p_w_given_dino = (word_counts["dino"].get(w, 0.0) + 1) / (sum(word_counts["dino"].values()) + v) 
    p_w_given_crypto = (word_counts["crypto"].get(w, 0.0) + 1) / (sum(word_counts["crypto"].values()) + v)

    log_prob_dino += math.log(cnt * p_w_given_dino / p_word)
    log_prob_crypto += math.log(cnt * p_w_given_crypto / p_word)

print("Score(dino)  :", math.exp(log_prob_dino + math.log(prior_dino)))
print("Score(crypto):", math.exp(log_prob_crypto + math.log(prior_crypto)))
```

Another approach is:

```
prior_dino = (priors["dino"] / sum(priors.values()))
prior_crypto = (priors["crypto"] / sum(priors.values()))
for w, cnt in list(counts.items()):
    p_word = vocab[w] / sum(vocab.values())
    p_w_given_dino = (word_counts["dino"].get(w, 0.0) + 1) / (sum(word_counts["dino"].values()) + v) 
    p_w_given_crypto = (word_counts["crypto"].get(w, 0.0) + 1) / (sum(word_counts["crypto"].values()) + v)
    prob_dino *= p_w_given_dino
    prob_crypto *= p_w_given_crypto
t_prior_dino = prob_dino * prior_dino
t_prior_crypto = prob_crypto * prior_crypto
```

On the second approach I got very small values.

Which one is correct, or are both of them correct?

Comment: The second approach multiplies probabilities, which might be just barely above zero, giving a total result after multiplication close to zero. Using log() evades that problem.

Comment: @user3760780: result from both are considerable right? just way of representation is changing

Comment: After using log() you should still get the highest score for the most probable class. Aside, I think you aren't using `p_word` in the second approach. You are also using `cnt` only in the first approach.

Answer (score 3):

These are completely equivalent approaches. The first one however is the preferable one, as working on logarithms of probabilities makes the whole process more **numericaly stable**. Results should be identical (up to numerical errors).

However it appears that you have errors in second approach

```
prob_dino *= p_w_given_dino
```

does not use the fact, that you have `cnt` occurences; it should be something like

```
prob_dino *= pow(p_w_given_dino, cnt)
```

Comment: oh thanks buddy, actually I thought it will be multiplied when iterated by for loop, didnt striked that i am already getting count value and each word iterated only once